# number of binary matrices with constraints

Tags: combinatorics

I am interested in calculating the number of binary matrices of dimension $n$ by $k$ where each row has at least one non-zero element and each column has at least one non-zero element.
I got the following equation:
$M(n, k) = 2^{n \times k} - \sum_{i=1}^{n} (-1)^i \binom{n}{i} 2^{k \times (n - i)} - \sum_{i=1}^{k} (-1)^i \binom{k}{i} 2^{n \times (k - i)} + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{k} (-1)^{i+j} \binom{n}{i} \binom{k}{j} 2^{(n - i) \times (k - j)}
$
is it correct?

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: yes, is this equation correct?

Comment: Your formula is confirmed by [Brian M Scott's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/440222/). To see this, expand the $\left(2^{n-k}-1\right)^m$ in his formula using the binomial theorem.